# Is there some easy way to add another HDD to a volume?

Tags: 16.04, server, lvm, gpt, storage

Let me preface by saying, I don't really know what I'm doing when it comes to ubuntu.

I added a 4TB drive to my media server, and I've been trying for the last few days to combine that space with the 1TB drive that has Ubuntu and all my media files.

I've partitioned the 4TB drive (`/dev/sdb1`) and added it to the same volume (`ubuntu-vg`) that the device that has the rest of the files (`/dev/sdb3`), however, when I attempt to extend the volume, it returns the following response:

```
New size (953861 extents) matches existing size (953861 extents)
```

When I attempt to resize, it returns the volume it returns the following response:

```
resize2fs 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
resize2fs: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-volume
Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.
```

Any guidance or help on how to add the storage of the 4TB drive (`/dev/sdb/`)to the 1TB drive (`/dev/sda/`) would be hugely appreciated. I'm afraid that what I'm doing at this point may be doing more harm than good.

If it helps at all, here is what is returned by `fdisk -l`

```
Disk /dev/sda: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 729EB966-0F7C-423C-8238-F9ABAB4DE969

Device       Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1     2048    1050623    1048576   512M EFI System
/dev/sda2  1050624    2050047     999424   488M Linux filesystem
/dev/sda3  2050048 1953523711 1951473664 930.5G Linux LVM


Disk /dev/sdb: 3.7 TiB, 4000787030016 bytes, 7814037168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 1004D293-2A88-4664-8943-1E686E33F864

Device     Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdb1   2048 7814035455 7814033408  3.7T Linux filesystem


Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root: 914.7 GiB, 982104670208 bytes, 1918173184 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1: 15.9 GiB, 17045651456 bytes, 33292288 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-volume: 3.7 TiB, 4000783007744 bytes, 7814029312 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

**Edit**

Results of pvs

```
PV         VG        Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree
/dev/sda3  ubuntu-vg lvm2 a--  930.53g    0
/dev/sdb1  ubuntu-vg lvm2 a--    3.64t    0
```

Results of vgs

```
VG        #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize VFree
ubuntu-vg   2   3   0 wz--n- 4.55t    0
```

Comment: Your system uses LVM. Please show the output of `pvs` (physical volume show) and `vgs` (volume group show).

Comment: @AlexP added pvs and vgs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your PV's and VG's

You have to extend first your Volume Group as your new physical was created

`vgextend ubuntu-vg /dev/sdb1`

scan it again so you can check

`pvscan`

then

`lvdisplay`

for example `lvdisplay` outputs something like this

> --- Logical volume ---
>
> LV Name                /dev/ubuntu-vg/rootfs
>
> LV Size               20.62  GiB

From here on it will show your logical volumes that you want to increase the size, you can increase it using this.

`lvextend /dev/ubuntu-vg/rootfs /dev/sdb1`

but you are not then you have to resize it to take effect

`resize2fs /dev/ubuntu-vg/rootfs`

Hope this helps.

Comment: this was just about it, i ended up doing the same exact thing, but i got rid of another volume that i had created

Comment: glad I can help you with this. Cheers! Enjoy Linux!